# Numeric DropDownListFor with Entity Framework - Selected item not being set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

Environment: Entity Framework (v6.0) with MVC and Razor.  Backend is SQL Server.

HTML helper DropDownListFor() is working perfectly for a **string** column on the database.  However, when I use a **decimal** column with a numeric dropdownlist the framework does not select the value loaded from the database when the form is rendered.

I assume this is related to the fact that DropDownListFor() contains strings for both Text and Value, and cannot match the decimal value from the database, so SelectedItem is not determined.

I've tried casting within the HTML helper, but fails either at compile or runtime.  All examples I can find assume you want to select a string, not a number.

Any help gratefully received.
Thanks.

View code:  the problem field is **CollarSize**.  The dropdownlist is CollarSizeSelect.

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollarSize, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CollarSize, Model.CollarSizeSelect, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CollarSize, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

The class definition contains the column defined thus:

```
public Nullable<decimal> CollarSize { get; set; }
```

CollarSize dropdown list is built as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChestSizeSelect
{
    get
    {
        return GetSelectNumberRange(32, 60, (decimal)1.0);
    }
}

private static List<SelectListItem> GetSelectNumberRange(int start, int end, decimal increment)
{
    List<SelectListItem> numlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (decimal i = start; i <= end; i = i + increment)
    {
       numlist.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString()});
    }
    return numlist;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `decimal` in html. If the value of `CollarSize` matches exactly the value of one of your options (i.e. using `ToString()`) then that option will be displayed

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but got InvalidOperationException.  _Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions._  I tried: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CollarSize.ToString(),`

Comment: No, I don't mean to do that! What is the value of `CollarSize`. If its (say)  `42` and you have an option with `value="42"` then it will be selected. Does the value of `CollarSize` match exactly the value of one of your options

Comment: Yes, there is a match e.g. CollarSize = 15.0, CollarSizeSelect has an entry for "15.0" (string).

Comment: Works fine for me - refer this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cmRbQ3). I suspect `CollarSize.ToString()` is not returning `"15.0"`

Comment: Stephen, many thanks for taking the time to set up a test showing how it should work.  Being new to MVC, it was instructive to me.  However, the problem was actually related to the database schema.  I found this because when I set the dropdown select list to 2 decimal places it worked, i.e. **15.00M** worked, but **15.0M** did not.  The db schema defined the column as decimal(5,2) and Entity Framework enforced this (I used MVC's Schema First to create the model class from the db). Your example was ideal, but the problem was not in the code sample I supplied so impossible for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not the construction of the SelectList, but due to the underlying database schema.

The database column:

```
CollarSize decimal(5, 2) NULL,
```

I used Entity Framework to build the model from the database (wizard option "EF Designer from database").  EF generated the field in the generated model:

```
public Nullable<decimal> CollarSize { get; set; }
```

The SelectList I generated to populate the DropDownListFor() contained a list of decimal items, but these items had a precision of a one decimal place, i.e. **15.0M**.  However, EF preserved the original precision, so when the DropDownList was being populated the Selected item could not be found since it was comparing **15.0** with **15.00**.

My solution was to build the SelectList with explicit precision:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CollarSizeSelect
{
    get
    {
         return new SelectList(new List<decimal> { 14.00M, 14.50M, 15.00M, 15.50M...
    }
}
```